# Unknown user shown in my user panel

Tags: login, users

I found a stranger in my user panel, I do not remember that I have added this user.
The users in my `/etc/passwd` are listed below:

```
root
daemon
bin
sys
sync
games
man
lp
mail
news
uucp
proxy
www-data
backup
list
irc
gnats
nobody
systemd-timesync
systemd-network
systemd-resolve
systemd-bus-proxy
syslog
_apt
messagebus
uuidd
lightdm
whoopsie
avahi-autoipd
avahi
dnsmasq
colord
speech-dispatcher
hplip
kernoops
pulse
rtkit
saned
usbmux
l0o0
sshd
strongswan
ftp
aftp
mongodb
```

The stranger **Aaron Kili** is not listed in the list. 
Is this a serious problem ? How can I remove this user?

**UPDATE**

```
l0o0:x:1000:1000:l0o0,,,:/home/l0o0:/usr/bin/zsh
aftp:x:1002:1002:Aaron Kili, Contributor:/home/aftp:/bin/bash
```

`l0o0` is my default user. I have googled [Aaron Kili](https://ug.linkedin.com/in/aaronkilik), maybe I have downloaded some soft from the web.

This is what I found in my command history.

```
3749  sudo useradd -m -c "Aaron Kili, Contributor" -s /bin/bash aftp
3750  sudo passwd aftp
3751  echo "aftp" | sudo tee -a /etc/vsftpd.userlist
3757  cd aftp
3768  sudo chmod a-w /home/aftp
```

[image: The screen shot of my user panel]

Comment: Userid `l0o0` looks strange. `egrep 'l0o0|Aaron' /etc/passwd` to be sure. Then `sudo usermod --expiredate 1 l0o0` to forbid logins from that userid). Reboot.  Then look at/inspect the files in `~l0o0`

Comment: @waltinator I have googled aaron kili, he is a Linux Technical Writer and Editor, maybe I download some softs from his page. But Why does this Aaron Kili show in my user panel?

Comment: The LinkedIn page indicates that user is from Uganda. I'd look in their home directory and see what you find. They may have hacked in using a background service like ssh or ftp. Do you have any open ports, or file/screen sharing, or default passwords set up?

Comment: @waltinator don't you mean 1002?

Comment: @waltinator, 1002 is stranger user.

Comment: @heynnema, I have a ssh server and TeamViewer.  I do not know what open ports are there yet

Comment: I have removed this user by `sudo deluser aftp`

Comment: Did you keep a copy of the `HOME` directory? Did you investigate what's in `~aftp`? Did you try to understand if  it's part of TeamViewer? Simply blowing it away is often unwise.

Comment: @waltinator, I was very confused at that time and delete the user. I think this user have nothing with TeamViewer. The `TeamViewer` is installed before 2017-9-1. I have found some commands in my history. Maybe he want to run vsftp in my laptop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you did not add the user, then your system may be compromised. Take your system off the network immediately so you do not reveal even more to the attacker while you investigate.

Deleting the intruder's account is not adequate. If they had the power to add a user, they had the power to install any number of backdoors that you won't find.

If you believe your system to be compromised, then fully reinstall, and restore your data from backups. This is exactly why you have backups.

If you added dirty software from the dirty internet, and you did not expect it to add the user, then it's behaving like malware. Treat it like malware and reinstall.